# Failed to open a connection to the database. "This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL server 2005 are supported"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-2.0

guys I am working on a legacy system of ASP.Net 2.0. My problem is when I tried to add a data source into a RDLC report wizard it gives me the error shown in screenshot

[image: error screenshot]

Tools use Visual Studio 2008 with SQL Server 2016.

Note: The laptop is provided by company and does not allow me to install any software.
Please guys help me I'm stuck and tried everything in my knowledge.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I fear you may be out of luck.  I saw this a few times around when SQL 2012 was released. Specifically in that it was a version number greater than 10. Your best bet is to upgrade Visual Studio to something much newer; of course doing that removes easy maintenance of reports, so you'll also need to report writer tools from SQL Reporting Server

Comment: Seems like there is no solution...